# Создать класс «множество целых чисел»

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Я решил данную задачу через динамический массив, но мне бы хотелось ее переделать: заменить массив на контейнер vector. Вопрос заключается в том, что мне не особо понятно, как работать с перегруженными операторами, если мы заменили наш массив на контейнер.К примеру:как к одному *вектору(поле класса)* присвоить значения *другого вектора* того же класса, разных объектов.
Искал довольно долго, но толком ничего не нашел. Было бы здорово, если бы направили или объяснили весь процесс работы с vector-ом.
Что по итогу у меня есть:

1. Есть функция-член, которая получает рандомные(уникальные) числа и добавляет их в контейнер.

```
set_of_integers& set_of_integers::get_random_elements(const int32_t &elements) {
std::random_device rd{};
std::mt19937 random{rd()};
int32_t number{ 0 };

for (size_t i = 0; i < elements;) {
    bool unique = true;
    number = random() % 50;

    for (auto& index : Z) {
        if (index == number) {
            unique = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (unique) {
        Z.push_back(number);
        (++i);
    }
}
std::shuffle(begin(Z), end(Z), random);
return *this;}
```

2. Есть фукнции-члены print(),check() - проверяет есть ли число(элемент) в контейнере:

```
void set_of_integers::check(const int32_t& num) {
    if (Z.empty()) {
        std::cout << "\nNo elements";
    }
    else {
        if (std::find(Z.begin(), Z.end(), num) != Z.end())
            std::cout << "\nYes!";
        else
            std::cout << "\nNo!";
    }
}

void set_of_integers::print() {
    std::cout << "Elements{ ";
    for (const auto& elements : Z) {
        std::cout << elements << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << "};\n";
}
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос — то обычным присвоением. `Z = v.Z`, где `v` — другой объект.

Comment: Создаю объекты A,B класса set_of_integers. Получил элементы путем рандомизации, затем хочу присвоить элементы B к А (например таким образом: `А+=В`). Вызывается перегрузка оператора - дальше в тупике: `this->Z+=B.Z`; .С утра подумал, что косяк мой заключается в том, что контейнеры - это шаблоны классов. Возможно есть какая-то специфика,о которой мне пока не дано знать.

Comment: "Огласите весь список" (с) — в смысле дайте код посмотреть.

Comment: Стоп-стоп... Вы для векторов хотите выполнять `+=`? Так это не называется "*присвоить*"! Вы хотите добавить элементы B к A, или прибавить к каждому элементу A значение соответствующего элемента B? Из вашей формулировки "присвоить к" следует только одно — неверное использование терминологии.

Comment: Справедливо. Тогда лучше "сложить значение"?
`set_of_integers operator+=(const set_of_integers& X) 
{ 
this->Z += X.Z; return(*this); 
}`

Comment: Правильно - "сложить и присвоить первоначальному" или `operator+=()`. А просто сложить это `operator+()`, который не изменяет свои операнды а создает новый объект.

Comment: Не знаю, как лучше, главное — чтобы было понятно и однозначно. Пока я так и не понял, что именно вам нужно.

Comment: @Harry Крайне не понимаю к чему эта придирчивость, особенно тогда, когда Вам показал код. По поводу "присвоения" - да, накосячил.

Comment: Я не придираюсь, я не понимаю, какое именно действие вы хотите реализовать..

Comment: @Harry У меня есть два объекта А и В, в классе котором находится vector целых чисел,размер который задан пользователем.  После рандомизирования, я получаю некоторые числа: допустим вектор объекта `A` имеет следующие элементы: `{1,2,3}`, а `B {4,5,6}`. Как мне получить `{1,2,3,4,5,6}`,через перегрузку оператора (`A+=B`),чтобы тем самым не нарушать логику?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После пояснений в комментариях стало понятнее. Вот пример, как это мжно написать (все несущественное выброшено). Писал специально попроще, через обычный `push_back`.

```
struct A
{
    vector<int> v;
    A& operator +=(const A& a)
    {
        for(int i: a.v) v.push_back(i);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

А [здесь](https://ideone.com/hKINpa) — пример, как это работает в программе.

Кстати, меня несколько смущает выбор для множества контейнера `vector` — все же операции поиска и вставки O(N) в общем случае, даже если постоянно сортировать, ничего хорошего не получится. Но к вопросу это не относится.

Comment: Благодарю Вас! В принципе тем же самым и занимался(методом `push_back`). Однако,мне казалось, что это не совсем...хм..логично что ли. В задаче сказано, что нельзя сортировать массив(вектор) поэтому,условно, тот же `set` я не использую. Ссылка не работает.
**P.S. через впн зашел.**

Answer (score 0):

Ну в вопросе действительно путаница с терминологией. Присвоение это `operator=()`. А то что вы дальше пишете, это `operator+=()`. Реализуется так же как и перегрузка всех остальных операторов. Причем, поскольку для `vector<>` уже есть `operator=()`, вам его делать самостоятельно не надо. Будет `Z = B.Z`.
А `operator+=()` нужно написать самому. Если он у вас уже написан, то только поменять синтаксис. Но в общем

```
while()
{
   Z[i] += B.Z[i];
}
```

Только нужно конечно проверять границы массивов, т.к. один массив может быть меньше другого.

Comment: Мне нужно объединить первый вектор со вторым.Т.е.: `A{1,2,3}; B{4,5,6}` -> `A{1,2,3,4,5,6}`.